# How to convert UTC Date Time to Local Date time without TimeZoneInfo class?

Tags: c#-4.0

i want to convert UTC date time to local date time by myself and do not want to use .net TimeZoneInfo or other classs about this.

i know Tehran is a GMT offset of +03:30 i use code below to convert UTC Date time to tehran (my local computer is in this location):

```
 DateTime dt = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(3.30);
```

it shows time like 5/2/2014 8:32:05 PM but Tehran time is 5/2/2014 9:32:05 PM it has one Hour deference.
How can i fixed it?

Comment: Daylight savings time?

Comment: *Why* do you not want to use `TimeZoneInfo` or something similar?

Comment: @Jon Skeet, because some of countries are not install on windows time zone and TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones() can not works with theme

Comment: That just means you should use a better time zone database :) See my answer.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, your solution and way is great but ,what about if i do not want to use third party codes in my project?

Comment: Then you need to build all the knowledge of all the time zones you're interested in yourself. Why reinvent the wheel? (And take it from me, it's a painful wheel to reinvent.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet OK, you have right man :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i know Tehran is a GMT offset of +03:30

Well, that's its offset from UTC in *standard* time, but it's currently observing daylight saving time ([details](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/iran/tehran)). So the current UTC offset is actually +04:30, hence the difference of an hour.

I suspect you're *really* off by more than an hour though, are you're adding an offset of 3.3 hours, which is 3 hours and 18 minutes. The literal `3.30` doesn't mean "3 hours and 30 minutes", it means 3.30 as a `double` literal. If you want 3 hours and 30 minutes, that's 3 and a half hours, so you'd need to use `3.5` instead. The time in Tehran when you posted was 9:46 PM... so I suspect you actually *ran* the code at 9:44 PM.

This sort of thing is why you should really, really, really use a proper time-zone-aware system rather than trying to code it yourself. Personally I wouldn't use `TimeZoneInfo` - I'd use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library which allows you to either use the Windows time zones via `TimeZoneInfo`, or the [IANA time zone database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones). The latter - also known as Olsen, or TZDB, or zoneinfo, is the most commonly-used time zone database on non-Windows platforms.